# How can I get a higher voltage from this boost converter built with an NE555?

Tags: boost, 555, coil, step-up

I built a boost converter, but it only reaches 130V. I want it to drive a Geiger-Müller tube at about 380V.

Is there any posibility to get that voltage from this circuit?

I changed the coil to a bigger one and the voltage jumped from ~80V to 130V. The values in the schematic are the ones that give me the highest voltage. I also tried a Schottky diode but it reduced the voltage to 80V so I changed it for a Zener diode.

Edit: It's an IRF840 not an IR7840.

[image]

Comment: a 1 uF snubber cap is *huge*. It will eat a lot of energy in the 4.7k resistor. Have you tried without the snubber?

Comment: IR7860 is not a valid component number I think. Please double check MOSFET and diode numbers and [edit].

Comment: If you anyway seemingly wind your inductor yourself..You can get higher stepup, by making a Flyback converter instead.

Comment: Do not use schottky, it does not help you at voltage. This is a flyback topology so you want the core to store energy. So you probably will be more successful with with air-gapped core.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický currently, it is not  Flyback, but a boost topology.

Comment: @tobalt sorry it's irf840

Comment: @tobalt I am sorry I made a mistake. Either way from some perspective it is the same :)

Comment: @MichalPodmanický Agreed. Everything you wrote still applies.. And modifying it with a second winding to turn into an actual Flyback topology might make it easier

Comment: 5 to 380 V just begs for a flyback.

Comment: Agreed about the flyback. With a BJT-only and Vce well within commonly found values, modest collector currents under a quarter amp, then a third winding towards the base would self-oscillate without a need for the 555. (Just verified with a quick simulation.) If willing to waste some energy then a stack of NE-2 could be used as a shunt to regulate the output voltage good enough for the flat Geiger-Mueller region.

Comment: @tobalt i add flyback by using big coil from old atx power supply, i dont dont know what exactly ratio this is but i got 140V. If I increase ratio then voltage will go up? I dont know exactly how it's working.

Comment: Yes. More secondary windings will increase output voltage. I suggest you really first work on that snubber.

Comment: @tobalt 1 uF is smalles cap i could found, i see my 555 is oscilating at 91kHz, i tryied to od flyback but i got 80v (primary: 13 turns, secoundary:  ~62)